# Error at Twitter SetCompletionHandler in iOS and PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, ios5, phonegap-plugins

I am new to iOS 5, I created in PhoneGap that support for iOS also. I used PhoneGap twitter plugin ( https://github.com/brianantonelli/phonegap-plugins/tree/a5c9d3a806514d1032c0673a9f97aeb3bcefd6bc/iPhone/Twitter ) it is work fine when I did not set Completion Handler. But, I want show alert to user. when `setCompletionHandler` I am getting Bad access error like this[image] .

I tried with sample apps with ARC and with out ARC also. But it is not working. Please give a solution for this. Every I am doing wrong.

if I create native app (not PhoneGap app). It works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it!  I'm using PhoneGap with Sharekit 2.0, but I found this helpful advice from a different PhoneGap twitter plugin:

If you have issues with the app crashing with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on iOS Simulator you may have a weak linking issue.

With your project highlighted in the left column in XCode go to Targets > Your Project > Build Settings > Linking > Other Linker Flags and replace `-weak_library` with `-weak-lSystem`

Comment: I had the same problem with EXC_BAD_ACCESS and setting a completion handler (not using PhoneGap), and this fixed it for me.